# What does 'Property implementation must have its declaration in the category 'TestingAdditions' mean?

Tags: swift

I was able to compile and generate a build. Then I installed the FirebaseFireStoreSwift pod and when I tried to build, I got this error in the FBLPromise+Testing 2.m file.

Any idea what it could be? It persists after uninstalling the pod.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by uninstalling the Firebase Analytics pod.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling all of the pods and installing them one at a time. That's how I debugged it.